# Sticky div on left, scroll on right

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was looking for portfolio ideas and I came across this particular one with a simple but beautiful design. I'm currently lost as to how to implement this layout, specifically the sticking element of it. I don't have any of my own code to compare, but can someone help me figure out how it works? Thanks!

http://melaniedaveid.com/

Also: I can get the concept to work for one section, just not a second. (i.e. going from the "About" section to the "Work" section.

Comment: Can press `F12` to view code

Comment: I'm aware, I just don't know how to implement it.

Comment: All the website resources are exposed, CSS, JS...etc... All you need is some reverse engineering, devtools and a bit of research and voila.. you make a similar website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is **sticky** positioning. 
There are several approaches to implement something like that. A good overview can be found [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-position-sticky-introduction-polyfills/).

I think the easiest solution is to use the CSS property `position:sticky;`. But it's not supported in many browsers. Fortunately there a number of polyfills to choose from like [position--sticky-](https://github.com/matthewp/position--sticky-) so you can use it just by now!

So how to use `position:sticky;`? You also need to specify `top` value which is required and specifies the distance from the top edge where the element will stick. So mostly you want it to be `top: 0;`. And then – as you scroll – when the element's distance from the top reaches 0, the element sticks.